# "Translation" of a Powershell parameter in CURL.EXE parameter

Tags: powershell, curl, session-variables

I would like to have

`Invoke-webrequest -Uri $LoginPageURL -SessionVariable WebSession`

"translated" in an appropriate *CURL.EXE* (not the alias CURL in PowerShell!) command for some reasons not to be discussed here.

However I am not able do so - please help.

Comment: What exactly are you not able to do?

Comment: Cannot use PowerShell the way I want due to this bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/1557783/invoke-webrequest-hangs-in-some-cases-unless-usebasicparsing-is-used. Therefore trying to achieve the same goal using CURL.EXE.

Comment: Yes, but *what have you tried and where are you stuck*?

Comment: I am not sure, what is unclear in my request. I am looking for the command to use as an equivalent to `Invoke-webrequest -Uri $LoginPageURL -SessionVariable WebSession`. curl is not pointing out a help when using `curl.exe --help | find "session"`.